# How do I use Node JS to execute a minecraft command on a wrapped minecraft server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, minecraft, child-process

I am making a node discord bot that would have the ability to control a minecraft server, but for some reason I cannot get the bot to execute minecraft commands on the server itself.

Right now the bot receives normal discord strings from messages and interprets them as commands. This is the code I use to start the server:

```
var svEnv = cp.spawn("java", [
   "-Xms4096M",
   "-Xmx4096M",
   "-jar",
   "server.jar",
   "nogui"
], { shell: true, detached: true, cwd: `${config.server.directoryPath}`, stdio: [
   "inherit",
   "inherit",
   "inherit",
   "ipc"
]});

svEnv.stdout.on("data", out => {
   console.log(`Server Feedback: ${out}`);
})

svEnv.stderr.on("data", err => {
   if (!(err == "^C")){
      console.error(`~Server Error: ${err}`);
   }
})
```

This is the code I'm using to try to execute the commands:

```
svEnv.stdin.write(`${cmd}\n`);
```

Whenever I attempt to use the code above to execute a command, the server doesn't respond at all. It's as if it doesn't even receive the input.

All the solutions I have visited, even those with the same exact use case as myself have said this is the correct way to implement this. I have to guess that the reason it doesn't work is because of the way I have the child process spawn configured.

Basically what I'm asking is how does the spawned process need to be configured to receive commands?

Please Note: This is my first time using the child process module in node js, so if you have any tips on how it works please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you set standard input to `inherit`. If you want to be able to write to it like that, then set it to `pipe` instead.

Comment: I tried setting the stdio option to "pipe" in the spawn parameters, however it still didn't seem to work. After tynkering with it a bit I found that the write method is indeed executing (according to the callback being executed without throwing errors). The minecraft server is simply not responding nor executing the command in any way. Do you have any ideas on how it can still be fixed